# How to make vim understand environment variables using curly braces

Tags: vim

I often use `gf` in vim to open files under cursor. Often these file paths use environment variables. When the environment variable is used without curly braces, vim has no trouble understanding it. But when curly braces are used, vim is unable to use the environment variable value.

This works for `gf`:

```
$tools/tools.json
```

This does NOT work for `gf`:

```
${tools}/tools.json
```

Is there a way to make vim understand the curly braces syntax for environment variables?
FYI, I am on Linux (SLES11SP3) in a TCSH shell, Vim 8.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `isfname` setting specifies the set of characters that can appear in file names.  It does not include `{` and `}` by default.

The default setting for most systems is:

```
isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=
```

If you change it to:

```
isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=,{,}
```

then the `gf` command will recognize `${tools}/tools/json` as a single file name.

Adding

```
set isfname+={,}
```

to your `.vimrc` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add these two lines to your `.vimrc` file:

```
set isfname+={,}
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname ,'\v\$\{(\w+)}','$\1','g')
```

Comment: Just adding { and } to isfname was enough. Did not need to do includeexpr. Thanks!

Comment: @shikhanshu: It looks like also setting `includeexpr` is helpful if you want to use `gf` on C `#include` directives and similar. (I was pleasantly surprised to see that `gf` on `#include <stdio.h>` jumps to `/usr/include/stdio.h`.)

Comment: @Keith: Yes, gf-ing to include files has worked for me (stdio.h jumping to /usr/include/stdio.h) etc. Did not need to do includeexpr for that either. The expression suggested by Meninx is basically replacing ${something} with $something. So I don't see what extra can be achieved as compared to just adding { and } to isfname

Comment: @shikhanshu: Now that I think about it, you're not going to have environment variable references in a `#include` directive. Maybe it makes more sense for similar constructs in other languages?

Comment: Please notice that if applying the trick into ```$()```, please do remember to taking care of this case ```$(shell $(xxx)/xx/x)```. The trailing ```)``` would be included in fname,  as ```$xxx/xx/x)```